# How to export Rich Text fields as HTML from Notes with LotusScript?

Tags: export, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I'm working on a data migration task, where I have to export a somewhat large Lotus Notes application into a blogging platform. My first task was to export the articles from Lotus Notes into CSV files.

I created a Agent in LotusScript to export the data into CSV files. I use a modified version of this [IBM DeveloperWorks forum post](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/CategoryAllThreadedweb/480b174af9f97924852575f60056bd84?OpenDocument). And it basically does the job. But the contents of the Rich Text field is stripped of any formatting. And this is not what I want, I want the Rich Text field rendered as HTML.

The [documentation for the GetItemValue](http://www.unitedtechnologysolutions.com/help/help8_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/dbbb58452d3909b58525731b004a1855?OpenDocument) method explicitly states that the text is rendered into plain text. So I began to research for something that would retrieve the HTML. I found the NotesMIMEEntity class and some sample code in the IBM article [How To Access HTML in a Rich Text Field Using LotusScript](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21091054).

But for the technique described in the above article to work, the Rich Text field need to have the property "Store Contents as HTML and MIME". And this is not the case with my Lotus Notes database. I tried to set the property on the fields in question, but it didn't do the trick.

Is it possible to use the NotesMIMEEntity and set the "Store Contents as HTML and MIME" property after the content has been added, to export the field rendered as HTML?

Or what are my options for exporting the Notes database Rich Text fields as HTML?

Bonus information: I'm using IBM Lotus Domino Designer version 8.5

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! At the moment I'm assigned to another task, but I will look into it later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at Midas' Rich Text LSX (http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/MidasLSX)

I haven't used the personally, but I remember them from years ago being the best option for working with Rich Text.  I'd bet it saves you a lot of headaches.

As for the NotesMIMEEntity class, I don't believe there is a way to convert RichText to MIME, only MIME to RichText (or retain the MIME within the document for emailing purposes).

Answer (score 10):

There is this fairly unknown command that does exactly what you want: retrieve the URL using the command OpenField.

Example that converts only the Body-field:

```
http://SERVER/your%5Fdatabase%5Fpath.nsf/NEW%5FVIEW/docid/Body?OpenField
```

Comment: 14 years Notes/Domino development and I didn't know about the OpenField command. Works a treat for something I'm developing now.

Comment: I did this and it sort of works.  If you have any pasted images or attached files it won't help you as it converts them to links back to the notes record.  I wish I could find something that will convert everything to HTML!

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I did it, using the OpenField command, see D.Bugger's post above

```
Function GetHtmlFromField(doc As NotesDocument, fieldname As String) As String
    Dim obj
    Set obj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    obj.open "GET", "http://www.mydomain.dk/database.nsf/0/" + doc.Universalid + "/" + fieldname + "?openfield&charset=utf-8", False, "", ""
    obj.send("")

    Dim html As String
    html = Trim$(obj.responseText)

    GetHtmlFromField = html
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

If you upgrade to Notes Domino 8.5.1 then you can use the new `ConvertToMIME` method of the `NotesDocument` class.  See the [docs](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_CONVERTTOMIME_METHOD.html). This should do what you want.

Alternativly the easiest way to get the Domino server to render the RichText will be to actually retrieve it via a url call.  Set up a simple form that just has the RichText field and then use your favourite HTTP api to pull in the page.  It should then be pretty straight forward to pull out the body.

Comment: I just got my evaluation license for Midas' Rich Text LSX. So I will try that. Thanks for the tip about upgrading 8.5.1. I will try that if LSX doesn't do it's magic.

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple.

Change the BODY field to Store contents as HTML and MIME

Open the doc in editmode.
Save.
Close.

You can now use the NotesMIMEEntity to get what you need from script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the NotesDXLExporter class to export the Rich Text and use an XSLT to transform the output to what you need.

Comment: Great info, I will look into that!

Comment: I tried to use the NotesDXLExporter, but it only renders the Rich Text field as some strange XML version of the Rich Text. It would be cumbersome to transform it to HTML. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 2):

I know you mentioned using LotusScript, but if you don't mind writing a small Java agent (in the Notes client), this can be done fairly easily - and there is no need to modify the existing form design.

The basic idea is to have your Java code open a particular document through a localhost http request (which is simple in Java) and to have your code capture that html output and save it back to that document. You basically allow the Domino rendering engine to do the heavy lifting.

You would want do this:

1. Create a form which contains only the rich-text field you want to convert, and with Content Type of HTML
2. Create a view with a selection formula for all of the documents you want to convert, and with a form formula which computes to the new form
3. Create the Java agent which just walks your view, and for each document gets its docid, opens a URL in the form http://SERVER/your_database_path.nsf/NEW_VIEW/docid?openDocument, grabs the http response and saves it.

I put up some sample code in a similar SO post here:

[How to convert text and rich text fields in a document to html using lotusscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356143/how-to-convert-text-and-rich-text-fields-in-a-document-to-html-using-lotusscript/1357566#1357566)

Comment: Great response! Always nice with code examples :-) I will try Midas' Rich Text LSX before turn to Java (just got my evaluation licence).

Answer (score 1):

Works in Domino 10 (have not tested with 9)

```
HTMLStrings$ = NotesRichTextItem .Converttohtml([options] ) As String
```

See documentation :

https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_CONVERTOHTML_METHOD_NOTESRICHTEXTITEM.html

**UPDATE (2022)**

HCL no longer support this method since version 11. The documentation does not include any info about the method.
I have made some tests and it still works in v12 but HCL recommended to not use it.

Comment: Hi, I use this function and it display mass character for Chinese. I am not sure if there is any option that we can handle Chinese?

Comment: @todaynowork I can't explain that, but try to use Options (you can find them in example in LS article).

https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_CONVERTOHTML_METHOD_NOTESRICHTEXTITEM.html?hl=converttohtml%2Crichtextitem%2Cjava

Comment: As of Domino release 11: "The convertToHTML method for the NotesRichTextItem class (LotusScript and Java) is not supported. References to it have been removed from the English web version of the Domino Designer Basic User Guide and Reference."

Comment: @D.Bugger you are right, I have also contacted HCL about that - and they confirmed that  method will be deprecated in v12. It is no longer in the documentation. I will update my post.

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi Found that out recently. Now trying with doc.ConvertToMIME and reading back MIME entities...

Answer (score 0):

Casper's recommendation above works well, but make sure the ACL is such to allow Anonymous Access otherwise your HTML will be the HTML from your login form

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to get the Richtext from the items specifically, you can use ?OpenDocument, which is documented (at least) here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_URL_COMMANDS_FOR_OPENING_DOCUMENTS_BY_KEY.html

OpenDocument also allows you to expand sections (I am unsure if OpenField does)

Syntax is:
http://Host/Database/View/DocumentUniversalID?OpenDocument

But be sure to include the charset parameter as well - Japanese documents were unreadable without specifying utf-8 as the charset.

Here is the method I use that takes a NotesDocument and returns the HTML for the doc as a string.

```
    private string ConvertDocumentToHml(Domino.NotesDocument doc, string sectionList = null)
    {
        var server = doc.ParentDatabase.Server.Split('/')[0];
        var dbPath = doc.ParentDatabase.FilePath;
        string viewName = "0";
        string documentId = doc.UniversalID.ToUpper();

        var ub = new UriBuilder();
        ub.Host = server;
        ub.Path = dbPath.Replace("\\", "/") + "/" + viewName + "/" + documentId;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sectionList))
        {
            ub.Query = "OpenDocument&charset=utf-8";
        }
        else
        {
            ub.Query = "OpenDocument&charset=utf-8&ExpandSection=" + sectionList;
        }

        var url = ub.ToString();

        var req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        try
        {
            var resp = req.GetResponse();
            string respText = null;

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                respText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return respText;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```