# Can we get URL details of a HotSpot Link inside a richtext content

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Is it possible to get the URL details of a Hotspot link inside a RichText content.

Like we can get the DocLink details inside richtext with the help of `NotesRichTextDocLink class`

Answer (score 0):

Access to Rich text using the native classes of Domino is relly limited. Thus, I'd suggest to export the Rich Text to HTML and parse it to get the url of the link.

See: [How to export Rich Text fields as HTML from Notes with LotusScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880511/how-to-export-rich-text-fields-as-html-from-notes-with-lotusscript)

My prefered way is ConvertToMIME.

Comment: It's just as easy to get it via DXL - easier, in fact, if what you're looking for happens not to be a URL (as it often may be when looking at hotspots), since an HTML export will just give you a link back to the document and a rich text offset value for the hotspot. With DXL, you can see formulas, etc.