# How to render HTML Body text in lotus notes using .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, lotus-notes, vb.net-2010, lotus-domino

Below code in  doc.GetItemValue("Body")  getting only the text without the html structure.i want to get the mail body in  html structure.(i am using  windows application,to show body of mail i used Web browser control.but i am unable to get body of mail in currect format.)

```
Dim lotusnotessession As New NotesSession()
lotusnotessession.Initialize(password)
Dim Db As NotesDatabase
Db = lotusnotessession.GetDatabase(server, Sfile, False)             
Dim inbox As NotesView = Db.GetView("($Inbox)")
Dim doc As NotesDocument = inbox.GetNthDocument(introw + 1)
doc.GetItemValue("Body")
```

Answer (score 0):

Lotus Notes email messages can be in two formats: native Notes rich text format, or MIME format. You will have to develop code to deal with both of these.  If the message is in MIME format and has a text/html body, you would use the [NotesMIMEEntity class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESMIMEENTITY_CLASS_OVERVIEW.html) and it's related classes to do this. It's not a trivial task, though, since you may have to traverse the structure of multipart MIME in order to find the appropriate part. If the message is in Notes rich text format, then take a look at the [answers to this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880511/how-to-export-rich-text-fields-as-html-from-notes-with-lotusscript).