# Is there a way to extract a Lotus Notes Rich Text field to keep the formatting?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am migrating from `Lotus Notes` to another application. I have a lot of the data migration working but one sticking point is the `Rich Text` field.

The users have text formatting in a field, with **underlining/strikethrough/colours etc..** which all represent something to them. I am unable to take the data from `Lotus Notes`, formatting and all, and extract it.

I've tried `GetFirstItem`, `GetItemValue`, `.TEXT, RichTextNavigator` and probably other methods that I can't remember now and neither are working. It's pulling the text as just plain text and I am losing the formatting.

The application we are moving it to has an ability to display `Rich Text` fields, so I was hoping I could pull the `Rich Text` field from `Lotus Notes`, with all it's formatting and simply display it in the new application.

Am I missing something in the `Domino library` that allows you to extract this data, as it must be stored in the `Lotus Notes` backend somehow, to pull that formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Read the answers to this earlier question. [How to export Rich Text fields as HTML from Notes with LotusScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880511/how-to-export-rich-text-fields-as-html-from-notes-with-lotusscript)  I strongly recommend looking at the MIDAS API referenced in the first answer as it will give you the best fidelity, but there are other options -- particularly in more recent versions.