# NotesRichTextItem ConvertToHtml method removed in Domino 12.0.2 - what are the alternatives?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I'm working on some legacy HTML-rendered forms containing rich text.

It looks as though the NotesRichTextItem ConvertToHTML method has been [removed](https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0073303&sys_kb_id=3f59e0f71bd49094c1f9759d1e4bcb99) from Domino versions 11 onward. I can do a workaround injecting javascript into my page then fetching the notes rich text using `?OpenField` url command however this produces `font` tags and all sorts of deprecated html.  What I'm missing is the ConvertToHTML options parameter (see HCL documentation [here](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_CONVERTOHTML_METHOD_NOTESRICHTEXTITEM.html)).

Is there an alternative way of getting a rich text field rendered into HTML? As an aside does anyone know why this was removed from later versions of Domino?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it hasn't actually been removed. It has simply been moved to unsupported status and all help and autocomplete data have been removed from the product.  What this means is that HCL has no intention of fixing the bugs in it, and wants to discourage you from using this method. It might be removed in the future, but as of now you can still use it.

As far as alternatives go, look at the answers to [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880511/how-to-export-rich-text-fields-as-html-from-notes-with-lotusscript). The MIDAS products mentioned in one of the answers are your best bet for clean and faithful HTML rendering, but they are not free.

The NotesDocument.convertToMIME method is mentioned in one answer, and I think that is the method that was most commonly used before the convertToHTML method showed up. I.e., first you use convertToMIME, then you read the document and use the NotesMIMEEntity class methods to get to the HTML. This [code from Julian Robichaux's site](https://www.nsftools.com/tips/ExportMime.lss) can help you with that.